# Create a Table based on a list from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have compiled a list of columns which I hope to build a table with. Is it possible to use a procedure to create a table based on this list? Ie

```
List
A
B
C

New_Table
Column A Column B Column C
```

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT INTO` might help. Read up on that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Im using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Why do you need a procedure? Why not just generate a `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: The list will be updated meaning the table will need to be updated. I'm attempting to automate the process

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877407/t-sql-how-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0):

**Customer** is atable consist of column **List** with rows:- A, B, C

What I've done is added a RowNum column on run time into the customer table which is dynamic. Due to this another column of row number got attached with List column. Using this:-

- RowNum=1 provides **A**
- RowNum=2 provides **B**
- RowNum=3 provides **C**

Here is the procedure as per your requirement. Please verify:-

```
create procedure newtable

@tablename NVARCHAR(1000)

as

Declare @col1 varchar(50),@col2 varchar(50),@col3 varchar(50), @cmd NVARCHAR(1000)

select @col1=List from (select List,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by List) as RowNum from customer)x where x.RowNum=1

select @col2=List from (select List,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by List) as RowNum from customer)x where x.RowNum=2

select @col3=List from (select List,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by List) as RowNum from customer)x where x.RowNum=3


set @cmd=N'Create Table '+@tablename+ N' (' + @col1+N' Varchar(50),'+@col2 + N' varchar(50),'+@col3+N' varchar(50))' ;

print @cmd

Exec(@cmd)
```

After this run your command:-
`exec newtable 'New_table'`