# Manipulating table structure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table full of data and I am looking to take the contents from one row and add it into column headers and then put its corresponding value below it in that column! The issue that I am trying to describe is best shown by the tables below:

Normal Table

[image]

Once this table has been created (this is a temporary table) I want to reconstruct the table to look like this

[image]

But I have searched everywhere on line and I can't seem to find out how to do this anywhere! I would be very grateful for the help!

Comment: When you say it's dynamic, you mean that the number of columns will depend on the number of distinct values in `TimeStamp` column?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the mistake in the question! I will edit it now! Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: looks like homework :) for me it looks like you need to write a query to create table in TSQL after the data are filled in. Question is, what are you planning to do when some additional data are entered to original table

Comment: It does look that way alright haha I made the tables as an example to show my problem! It was the easiest way to illustrate my problem!

Comment: @user3538102 I haven't done anything like this before, but I can point you to [Pivot tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx). Because it's dynamic, I think you can combine the principles of Pivot Tables with [Dynamic SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to create the `IN` part of the pivot query (will have to contain all distinct values from `Timestamp` column).

Comment: I believe this is relevant for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877407/t-sql-how-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-stored-procedures

first you use the loop to define all necessary columns based on distinct times in last column, second you use another loop to reorganize the data from original table and finally remove original table and rename the new one

Comment: I think it is bad practice to store values in headers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
  (
     sourceid  INT,
     name      VARCHAR(50),
     value     VARCHAR(50),
     timestamp NUMERIC(10, 2)
  )

INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES      (1,
             'Mark',
             '99%',
             9.00),
            (1,
             'Mark',
             '75%',
             9.30),
            (1,
             'Mark',
             '60%',
             10.00),
            (1,
             'Mark',
             '85%',
             10.30),
            (2,
             'John',
             '50%',
             9.00),
            (2,
             'John',
             '30%',
             9.30),
            (2,
             'John',
             '65%',
             10.00),
            (2,
             'John',
             '79%',
             10.30)

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';

SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(timestamp)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT p.timestamp
        FROM   #table1 AS p) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
select *from (SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM #table1
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  MAX(VALUE) FOR TIMESTAMP IN ('
           + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
           + ')
) AS p)tb
order by tb.sourceid';

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql;

DROP TABLE #table1
```

Comment: I can't do it like this because the table is going to grow with more people and it needs to be able to handle this!

Comment: if you need to keep content of the original table, then execute this as after insert trigger... after you insert new record in original table, you alter the structure of dynamic table if necessary by adding new column, if not, you just add new record

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dynamic Pivot` to do this.

```
DECLARE @sql     NVARCHAR(max),
        @collist VARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @collist += Isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Quotename(timestamp)), '')+ ','
FROM   #pivo
GROUP  BY timestamp

SELECT @collist = LEFT(@collist, Len(@collist) - 1)

SET @sql='select * from Tablename
pivot (max(Value) for timestamp in('
         + @collist + '))piv'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I am getting the following errors `is too long. Maximum length is 128` its talking about the dates

Comment: @user3538102 - post the full error. It looks you like something wrong with your data. for your sample data it is working fine

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic Pivot code for MS SQL

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders varchar(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =
COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar(5),Timestamp,108) + ']', '[' + CONVERT(varchar(5),Timestamp,108)+ ']'  )
FROM (SELECT Timestamp FROM Table1 GROUP BY Timestamp ) UC

DECLARE @PQuery varchar(MAX) = '
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, CONVERT(varchar(5),Timestamp,108) AS Timestamp, Value FROM Table1 T0) T1
    PIVOT (MAX([value]) FOR CONVERT(varchar(5),Timestamp,108) IN (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ') ) AS P'

EXECUTE (@PQuery)
```

Comment: I got the following error `Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.`

Comment: Edited to handle datetime conversion