# CREATE several tables by looping through ROWS in a particular table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, rows, create-table

How can I, in MySQL using loop through the **Subject** table and create a table for each subject as shown below using **Math**, **Econs**, **Chem** as examples. Bring in php only as a last resort.

Table: **SUBJECTS**

### |  Subject |   unit    |   staff       |

|  Math    |   3       |   Mr James    |
 |  Econs   |   1       |   Dr Smith    |
 |  Chem    |   2       |   Mrs Aisha   |

table: **MATHS**

### Student |  TEST1  |   TEST2   |   EXAM    |

101     | 10      |     20    |     30    |
105     | 11      |     09    |     45    |

table: **ECONS**

### Student |  TEST1  |   TEST2   |   EXAM    |

101     | 10      |     20    |     30    |
105     | 11      |     09    |     45    |

table: **CHEM**

### Student |  TEST1  |   TEST2   |   EXAM    |

101     | 10      |     20    |     30    |
105     | 11      |     09    |     45    |

Comment: Take a look at [`LOOP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html). And `CREATE` at table on each iteration.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Iam sure it requires a procedure to loop while creating a table for each subject but I dont know how to write Procedures in MySQL.

Comment: This is not a good database design. Seriously you are going to create a maintenance nightmare. You need to read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877407/t-sql-how-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-stored-procedures/10877522#10877522 I urge you not to create table dynamically.

Comment: @Namphibian, Thank you all guys for contribution. The Table creation is going to be a one time thing. I need about table for Marksheet for each of the 500 courses.  I am working on it. I realize I will need to learn MySQL Curso Procedure to do that. I wished I have a pro  throw  more light in that direction.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, when I come up with something meaningful, I will present it. Thank you sir.

Comment: @SamRans give me a moment and I will show you what you can do. No need for so many tables trust me.

Comment: @SamRans goo see my rather simplified design and try understand the concepts in there.

Answer (score 0):

When designing your database you first need to identify all the entities that will be needed to support your goals. In your case you need to keep track of students and how their results in various courses/subjects.

Based on this we can identify the following entities:

1. Subjects such as math,chemistry etc.
2. Students who take tests and exams for those subjects.
3. Staff members who are responsible for teaching the subjects and preparing the exams/test.
4. Different types of tests i.e. class test, exams and so forth.
5. The results of students for a particular type of test in a particular subject.

So based on this (rather simplified_ scenario we only need 5 tables. The second thing is to identify the relationships between the entities. Lets review them.

1. A subject can only be presented by one staff member but a staff member can present many subjects. For example math is only taught by Mr Jones but Mr Jones teaches math and science. This is what we call a one to many relationship.
2. A student can have many results in many subject and a subject can have many students with many results. For example Student 1 took an exam and a test in math with two different results. The math subject might have 100's of student each with one or more result recorded. This is a many to many relationship.
3. Each result of a student will be of some type either a exam or a test. Thus there is one to many relationship here. There is only one exam type but math,science,geography and history all use this exam type.

So based on all of this  have created a small demo database. I will take you through it.

Here is a visual representation of the structure:
[image]

Here is the code for the database.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `coursedb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `coursedb`.`staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb`.`staff` (
 `staff_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `staff_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `staff_surname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `staff_title` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`staff_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `coursedb`.`subject`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb`.`subject` (
`subject_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`subject_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
`staff_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`subject_ID`),
INDEX `fk_subject_staff_idx` (`staff_ID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_staff`
  FOREIGN KEY (`staff_ID`)
  REFERENCES `coursedb`.`staff` (`staff_ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `coursedb`.`student`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb`.`student` (
  `student_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `coursedb`.`subject_result_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb`.`subject_result_type` (
  `subject_result_type_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject_result_type_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_result_type_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `coursedb`.`subject_student_result`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb`.`subject_student_result` (
  `subject_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `student_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subject_student_result_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `subject_student_result_score` INT NOT NULL,
  `subject_result_type_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_ID`, `student_ID`, `subject_student_result_date`),
  INDEX `fk_subject_student_result_subject1_idx` (`subject_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_subject_student_result_student1_idx` (`student_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_subject_student_result_subject_result_type1_idx`  (`subject_result_type_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_student_result_subject1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subject_ID`)
    REFERENCES `coursedb`.`subject` (`subject_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_student_result_student1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`student_ID`)
    REFERENCES `coursedb`.`student` (`student_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_student_result_subject_result_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subject_result_type_ID`)
    REFERENCES `coursedb`.`subject_result_type` (`subject_result_type_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursedb`.`subject` (
       `subject_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `subject_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
       `staff_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`subject_ID`),
       INDEX `fk_subject_staff_idx` (`staff_ID` ASC),
       CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_staff`
         FOREIGN KEY (`staff_ID`)
         REFERENCES `coursedb`.`staff` (`staff_ID`)
         ON DELETE NO ACTION
         ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
     ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Lets start adding some data so you can see how this all fits together. First lets add two staff members Mr Jones and Miss Grumpy.

Execute the following code:

```
INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`staff`
(
  `staff_name`,
  `staff_surname`,
  `staff_title` 
)
SELECT 'James', 'Jones','Mr'
UNION 
SELECT 'Pot','Grumpy','Miss';
```

This will insert the two staff members. If you look at the newly inserted data by executing a `SELECT` statement you will find the following data:

```
 staff_ID staff_name  staff_surname  staff_title
 '1',     'James',    'Jones',       'Mr'
 '2',     'Pot',      'Grumpy',      'Miss'
```

Notice how the database has assigned a ID number to these staff members? This is the primary key for the staff member and we use this to identify the row in the staff tables. I am keeping this to auto numbers for the moment but there are several options here.

We now need to create the courses that these two staff members teach. Mr Jones teaches math and science and Miss Grump teaches Art. Lets create the subjects and link them to the staff members. This can be done by the following code:

```
INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject`
(
    `subject_name`,
    `staff_ID`
)
VALUES
(
    'Math',
     1
);


INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject`
(
    `subject_name`,
    `staff_ID`
)
VALUES
(
     'Science',
      1
);


INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject`
(
    `subject_name`,
    `staff_ID`
)
VALUES
(
  'Art',
   2
);
```

You can now see which subjects Mr Jones teaches by executing the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   staff stf
INNER JOIN `subject` sub
      ON stf.staff_ID = sub.staff_ID
WHERE stf.staff_ID =1;
```

So before we can track how a student is doing in their courses there is two pieces of information that is missing. The type of result i.e. exam or test and of course some students. So lets add them.

```
INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`student`
(
   `student_name`
)
VALUES
(
    'Student 1'
);


INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject_result_type`
(
  `subject_result_type_name`
)
SELECT 'Test'
UNION 
SELECT 'Exam'
```

With this out of the way lets record some results for Student 1. Student one wrote 2 exams one in science one in math and Student 1 also did a art test. The following SQL will insert this data:

```
 INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject_student_result`
 (`subject_ID`,
  `student_ID`,
  `subject_student_result_date`,
  `subject_student_result_score`,
  `subject_result_type_ID`
  )
  VALUES
  (
    1,
    1,
    CURDATE(),
    80,
    2
 );

 INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject_student_result`
 ( `subject_ID`,
   `student_ID`,
   `subject_student_result_date`,
   `subject_student_result_score`,
   `subject_result_type_ID`
 )
 VALUES
 (
    2,
    1,
    CURDATE(),
    60,
    2
 );
INSERT INTO `coursedb`.`subject_student_result`
(  `subject_ID`,
   `student_ID`,
   `subject_student_result_date`,
   `subject_student_result_score`,
   `subject_result_type_ID`
 )
 VALUES
 (
    3,
    1,
    CURDATE(),
    80,
    1
  );
```

You can now draw a report on a student and their results by executing the following query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM subject_student_result ssr
 INNER JOIN student std
       ON ssr.student_ID = std.student_ID
 INNER JOIN `subject` sub
       ON ssr.subject_ID = sub.subject_ID
 INNER JOIN subject_result_type srt
       ON ssr.subject_result_type_ID = srt.subject_result_type_ID
 INNER JOIN staff stf
       ON sub.staff_ID = stf.staff_ID
```

I suggest you work through this model and really understand what I am showing you. It will make your designs simpler and cleaner and much less maintenance.

Comment: thanks you you immense support. Being a novice, I shall take time to study and digest your contribution.