# Adding table in the stored procedure code

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am new to sql. I have a stored procedure where I need to add two columns which is of Table "dbo.AdditionProjectDetails". Here ProjectID is the primary key. Below is the code snippet as I cant add the whole here. Any help?

```
    SELECT  PBD.Proj_ID, case when Phase =1 then 'Phase I' when Phase=2 then 'Phase II'
                    Tasktype,Area_Name,ProjectName,OS_Name,PTCDD.Remarks 
                     FROM ProjectDetails (NOLOCK) PBD
                    inner join ProjectTestProcessDetails (NOLOCK) PTPD on PBD.Proj_ID =PTPD.Proj_ID
                    inner join ProjectTestCycleDet (NOLOCK) PTCD on PTCD.Proj_ID=PBD.Proj_ID
                    inner join ProjectTestCycleDuration (NOLOCK) PTCDD on PTCDD.Proj_ID=PBD.Proj_ID
                    inner join ProjectTestProcessCostDetails (NOLOCK) PTPCD on PTPCD.Proj_Test_PrepareID=PTPD.Proj_Test_PrepareID
                    inner join AreaMaster Am on Am.Area_ID =PBD.AreaID
                    inner join ProjectMaster PM on PM.ProjectID =PBD.PlatformID
                    inner join OSMaster OS on OS.OS_ID =PBD.OSID

                    where Status in ('S','R','C') and Tasktype,Area_Name,ProjectName,OS_Name,PTCDD.Remarks
group by PBD.Proj_ID,PBD.Created_by,PBD.Created_on,status,TaskGivenDate
                    order by PTCD.TaskEndDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link here is the explaination of the store procedure and also details what u want

[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

[T-SQL How to create tables dynamically in stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877407/t-sql-how-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-stored-procedures)