# How can I create a table with table name stored in a variable? - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In **SSIS Execute SQL Task**, I have this code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = 
        t.schema_id 
    WHERE t.name =  'tableName'  AND s.name = 'stg')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [stg].[tableName] (
        Col1 nvarchar(255),
        Col2 nvarchar(1800)
    )
END
```

How can I make `tableName` a variable so that I can change the name easily?

Comment: Sounds like you dynamically want to create tables?

Comment: Yes. I want to dynamically create tables.

Comment: See this answer on why it is a bad idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877407/t-sql-how-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-stored-procedures/10877522#10877522

Comment: Is there no other way to easily create a table with same properties/columns as the first one, other than changing the SQL statement?

Comment: Why do you need the same structure copied over and over again?

Comment: Because I will be inserting unique data that have similar datatypes for all columns in each table. Please help me. I have to create like 50 tables with same structures, and it would be tedious if I have to edit the SQL statement everytime.

Comment: why not add a column to one table called tableType or something

Answer (score 5):

Create a execute sql task then write this code in the SqlStatement with direct input type:

```
declare @sch nvarchar(10)   
        ,@tb nvarchar(50)
        ,@query nvarchar(1000)

Set @sch= ?
Set @tb= ?

IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = 
        t.schema_id 
    WHERE t.name =  @tb  AND s.name = @sch)
BEGIN
 set @query='CREATE TABLE '+@sch+'.'+@tb+' ( Col1 nvarchar(10),Col2 nvarchar(10) )'
 exec sp_executesql @query
END
```

Then map your variables in Parameter Mapping tab with Parameter Names 0 and 1 (in order of coming in the code)
Even you can create your columns dynamically with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to make it dynamic and flexible.
Declare three variables -

sTableName,sSchemaName,sSQL_GenerateTable

Declare a string variable by the name sSQL_GenerateTable and give the following value as Expression -

```
"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" +@[User::sTableName] + "' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + @[User::sSchemaName]+ "') BEGIN 
CREATE TABLE [" + @[User::sSchemaName]+ "].[" +@[User::sTableName] +"] (
    Col1 NVARCHAR(255)
    ,Col2 NVARCHAR(1800)
)
END "
```

In the "Execute SQL Task", set the 'SQLSourceType' as 'Variable' and give the above variable, set 'ResultSet' as 'None'.