# T-SQL / Create a table that his columns depend on rows of an other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i want to create a new table that has dynamic number of columns depending on the row values of an other table.
For example i have a table (table1) that has 2 columns named 'VALUE' and 'ISACTIVE' ('ISACTIVE' column takes the value 1 if we need to take into account this value as a column in the new table) and i need to create a new table that has:
number of columns (and column name) of new table = the values of table1 where Isactive = 1.

Comment: What should be the datatype of the columns that we create ?

Comment: Have you tried to create it dynamically (dynamic SQL query) based on your conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the below.This is assuming all the columns to be integer .we can modify accordingly if it is varchar .We need to alter the existing table and add a column called textval which defaults to '0' here

```
     drop table test
     create table test
    (
      value integer,
      isactive integer
    );
  alter table test add  textval nvarchar(max) default '0'
  insert into test (value,isactive) values (123,5);

   select * from test;
```

Now update the new columns based on the value of isactive .if it is 5 the new column will have upto col5 all beign integer and use this to create a new table

```
  begin 

   declare @i integer;
   set @i=1
   declare @isactive integer;
   declare @stmt nvarchar(max);
   declare @stmt2 nvarchar(max);
   declare @testval nvarchar(max);

   set @isactive= (select isactive from test)
   while (@i <=@isactive)
     begin
         declare @textval nvarchar(max);
         set @textval = (select textval from test)
        set @stmt= 'update test set textval = '''+ @textval +'col' +cast(@i 
        as varchar(100)) + ' ' + 'integer,'''

      execute sp_executesql @statement=@stmt
     set @i=@i+1;
    end 
  set @testval=(select left(replace(textval,'0col1','col1'),len(textval)-2) 
               from test)

   set @stmt2 ='create table tab1 ( ' + @testval + ' )';
   execute sp_executesql @statement=@stmt2;

  end
```

Comment: thx mate this is really helpfull. i also found an alternative way by building the 'update' statement inside a string using a cursor and it worked fine. Your way though is more advanced! thanks!

Comment: Thank you ...if you think the query was useful ,it will be great if you can vote for it since it can be used by others as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [attributeName] INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo].[NewTableName] 
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[FromTableName] WHERE ISACTIVE=1
```

Comment: this generates a new table with just 1 column (containing the values of table1 where isactive=1). what i need is to create a table that has:
number of columns of new table = number of rows of table1 where is active=1

Comment: You can't apply where condition on columns but if you want to copy only the structure of the table to a new table with selected columns then this is what you can use: SELECT attributeName1, attributeName2... INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo].[NewTableName] FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[FromTableName] WHERE 1=2

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to create it dynamically in a procedure based on your conditions. Read this question and answers , it will help.

[T-SQL How to create tables dynamically in stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877407/t-sql-how-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-stored-procedures)

Raw example

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLString = N'CREATE TABLE <table_name> ('
        -- Conditons here
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + '<column_name> <type>'

        -- End of conditions

    SET @SQLString = @SQLString + ')'

    EXEC (@SQLString)
```